# how to fix 404 error on shopware 6.5.4.0 for custom controller on custom plugin

Tags: plugins, shopware6, custom-error-pages

im working on a shopware 6.5.4.0 project, im building custom plugin.

in there exists a custom controller as below

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Nst\Storefront\Controller;

use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class CodesController extends StorefrontController
{
    /**
* @Route("/mystory", name="frontend.example.example", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"_routeScope"={"storefront"}})
*/

    public function showPage(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->renderStorefront('@Nst/storefront/page/example.html.twig');
    }
}
```

in my services.xml I have this below

```
   <service id="Nst\Storefront\Controller\CodesController" public="true">
            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
        </service>
```

in my routes I have this

```
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
        https://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <import resource="../../Storefront/Controller/**/*Controller.php" type="annotation" />
</routes>
```

the route is available when I run

```
bin/console debug:router | grep 'frontend.example.example'



frontend.example.example                                            GET           ANY      ANY    /mystory
```

but I still get 404 error, what could be the issue please help

Comment: Have you tried clearing the symfony cache with `bin/console cache:clear? 
and did you check that your plugin is actually installed and active?